# Intuition behind the definition of a derivative by Lang

Tags: derivatives, differential-topology

In Serge Lang's *Introduction to Differentiable Manifolds* he says that a function $f:U\to F$ is differentiable at a point $x_0\in U$ if there exists a linear map $\lambda$ of $E$ into $F$ such that, if we let $$f(x_0+y)=f(x_0)+\lambda y+\varphi(y)$$ for small $y$, then $\varphi$ is tangent to $0$.
Tangent to $0$ is defined as follows:

A real valued function of a real variable, defined on some neighborhood of $0$ is said to be $o(t)$ if $$\lim_{t\to 0}o(t)/t=0.$$

Let $E,F$ be two vector spaces, and $\varphi$ a mapping of a neighborhood of $0$ in $E$ into $F$. We say that $\varphi$ is tangent to $0$ if, given a neighborhood $W$ of $0$ in $F$, there exists a neighborhood $V$ of $0$ in $E$ such that $$\varphi(tV)\subset o(t)W$$

What is the intuition behind defining it in this manner?

Comment: Maybe it's because I'm drunk, but isn't the $\lambda y$ term merely the linear term (i.e., derivative) and $\varphi(y)$ the "bonus parts which vanish in the appropriate limit"? Just as if for a usual function in calculus 101 we would Taylor expand $f(x+h)=f(x)+f'(x)h+g(h)$ where $g(h)\sim o(h^{2})$. The derivative would naturally be the linear (first) term...well, the coefficient to $h$...

Comment: $\lambda$ is the derivative, but I don't particularly get what you mean about the "bonus parts which vanish in the appropriate limit". Nor do I understand the intuition behind using a real valued function for the definition of tangent near $0$.

Comment: First try to understand the similar definition of the derivative at a point for a mapping $f \colon {\mathbf R}^n \rightarrow {\mathbf R}^m$ in terms of linear approximations. This is discussed in Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds. Look also in Lang's Undergraduate Analysis for the definition of the derivative as a linear map. These will be more concrete than what he is doing in more general (potentially infinite-dimensional?) real vector spaces in his differential manifolds book.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lang is trying to say things in a way that also works in infinite dimensional spaces. There, not all norms on a vector space are equivalent, so he is avoiding a definition using metrics on $V$ and $W$, and assuming only that each vector space has a topology.  For finite dimensional spaces it is the same as the definition that does use metrics (and independent of the metric chosen, since all such induce the same topology).